# Jlist updating content using action listener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jlist

I have a Jframe that contains of two panel. 
In one panel named "panelA" , user select a category by selecting an item from JCombobox and then click on "update button". Then I have another panel named "panelB" that contains a Jlist and it showes a list of existing items in that selected category from "panelA".

I have a model class that does the logic part of the application using observer pattern. I send the changes using action listener from  panelA after clicking the button to the model class and model class does the work and prepares a list that contains filtered data. Then I need to some how get filtered data show on Jlist content on panelB .

Now My Problem is I don't know which method of the Jlist class updates the content the Jlist. Or it is better to say I don't know which method in Jlist class changes the datalist in Jlist. 
I just need a clue. 
Sorry if my question is not professional, I am very new at java and programing. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want a variable-size `JList`, you should initialize it with `JList(ListModel)`, using a list model that allows adding new elements to the list (like [`DefaultListModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html)).

Then you can add new elements like this:

```
DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel)list.getModel();
model.addElement(element);
```

Use generics if you are using Java 7:

```
DefaultListModel<MyClass> model = (DefaultListModel<MyClass>)list.getModel();
model.addElement(element);
```

Where `MyClass` is the `class` of the list elements.